# Jboss6.1 throws UnsupportedClassVersionError 51 but the jar is compiled by Jdk5

Tags: java, ubuntu, jboss

My system is:
Ubuntu 12
eclipse 4.3
Sun Jdk 6
Jboss 6.1
Maven 3+

When I start the Jboss with my application,there is a error:

[org.jboss.detailed.classloader.ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:mondrian.olap4j.FactoryJdbc41Impl$MondrianOlap4jCellSetJdbc41: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: mondrian/olap4j/FactoryJdbc41Impl$MondrianOlap4jCellSetJdbc41 : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

The version 51.0 means JDK 7

But I checked the mandrian-3.57.jar, the Manifest.MF says:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Created-By: 1.5.0_16-b02 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Built-By: buildguy

And there is only one mondrian.jar in my local disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manifest just gives the version of the JAR tool that built the JAR. It doesn't prove that the same version of javac was used. The version 51 shows unambiguously that it was compiled by the 1.7 javac.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder. You are right, I double checked the magic number of the classes, this class is "CAFE BABE 00 00 00 33", which means JDK 1.7.